# What factors influence the ordering of transactions in a block in HLF 1.4.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/txflow.html) for the transaction flow of hyperledger fabric it is mentioned that

*"The ordering service does not need to inspect the entire content of a transaction in order to perform its operation, it simply receives transactions from all channels in the network, orders them chronologically by channel, and creates blocks of transactions per channel."*

I have a couple of questions here

1. What does "chronological ordering" mean?. Does it mean that the transactions for a channel are ordered depending on the time they are received at the Ordering service node (Leader) ?
2. If two client applications are submitting an update transaction for the same key on the ledger almost at the same time [Let us call them tx1 (updating key x to value p) , tx2 (updating key x to value q)], all the endorsing peers will simulate the update transaction proposal and return the write set in the transaction proposal response. When the clients send these endorsement proposal requests to ordering service nodes , in which order will these update transactions be ordered in a block ?.

The order of transactions in the block can be tx1,tx2 OR tx2,tx1 , assuming the update transaction has only the write set and no read set , both the transactions in either orders are valid. What will be the final value of the key on the ledger [p or q] ?

I am trying to understand if the final value of x is deterministic , and what factors would influence it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does "chronological ordering" mean?. Does it mean that the transactions for a channel are ordered depending on the time they are received at the Ordering service node (Leader)?

In general, the orderer makes no guarantees about the order in which messages will be delivered just that messages will be delivered in the same order to all peer nodes.

In practice, the following generally holds true for the current orderer implementations:

Solo - messages should be delivered in the order in which they were received

Kafka - messages should be delivered in the order in which they were received by each orderer node and generally even in the order they are received across multiple ordering nodes.

This holds true for the latest fabric version as well.

> If two client applications are submitting an update transaction for the same key on the ledger almost at the same time [Let us call them tx1 (updating key x to value p) , tx2 (updating key x to value q)], all the endorsing peers will simulate the update transaction proposal and return the write set in the transaction proposal response. When the clients send these endorsement proposal requests to ordering service nodes, in which order will these update transactions be ordered in a block ?.

When you submit a transaction, the peer generates a read and write set. This read/write set is then used when the transaction is committed to the ledger. It contains the name of the variables to be read/written and their version when they were read. If, during the time between set creation and committing, a different transaction was committed and changed the version of the variable, the original transaction will be rejected during committal because the version when read is not the current version.

To address this, you will have to create data and transaction structures that avoid concurrently editing the same key, other you might get `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` error.